# In the NBA, do you get a free throw if you are fouled by the buzzer?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

What happens if an NBA player gets fouled right when the shot clock ends, and he gets the and 1. Would he be able to shoot the free throw?
Do the referees base this on game point, or just don't do it?

Comment: When the shot clock ends, or when the game clock ends?

Comment: I guess for both